# emit KeyPress in mono

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, sendkeys

Question: On click `button1` send `"a"` key to mainwindow. How can I do it? (Example please)

```
using System;  
using Gtk;  
namespace pressevent
{   
class MainClass 
{       
   public static void Main(string[] args)       
   {
            Application.Init();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
            win.KeyPressEvent += delegate(object o, KeyPressEventArgs a) {
                if(a.Event.Key == Gdk.Key.a)
                    Console.WriteLine("Key pressed");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Key not pressed");
            }; 
            Button btn1 = win.getButton1();
            btn1.Pressed += (sender, e) => 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Button1 pressed"); 
                                // Here code that send "a" key to MainWindow
            };
            win.Show(); Application.Run(); 
}}}
```

Thanks.
PS: Sorry my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Your design is wrong. If `Button1` is pressed it must call a method on `MainWindow` which has one argument: the `"a"` of your question.

On the main window, the event click calls the same method.

Generally speaking, do not put logic in your handlers. They are just entry points or dispatchers to method containing logic.

```
Application.Init();

MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
win.KeyPressEvent += (sender, e) =>
{
    win.MethodWithLogic(e.Event.Key);
}; 

Button btn1 = win.getButton1();
btn1.Pressed += (sender, e) => 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Button1 pressed"); 
    win.MethodWithLogic(Gdk.Key.a);
};

win.Show(); 
Application.Run();
```

And further, in MainWindow class (or via inheritance, create your own)

```
public void MethodWithLogic(Gdk.Key key)
{
  if(key == Gdk.Key.a)
      Console.WriteLine("Key pressed");
  else
      Console.WriteLine("Key not pressed");
}
```

(not tested, but you got the idea)